# Chrome Extension Storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently creating a chrome extension and I'm using chrome.storage.local.set and get in order to store and retrieve a UUID. Is there any storage mechanism that could survive reinstalls/deactivations of the extension? I have so far been unable to do that using chrome.storage.local or chrome.storage.sync.

Thanks

Comment: relevant discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210499/chrome-storage-local-persistence

Comment: looks like a duplicate of the link above.

Comment: Thanks, didn't come across that on my previous search!